# Identifying a window in time series data where data points are below set value

Tags: python, time-series

This is a small subset of my data:

```
                     heartrate
2018-01-01 00:00:00       67.0
2018-01-01 00:01:00       55.0
2018-01-01 00:02:00       60.0
2018-01-01 00:03:00       67.0
2018-01-01 00:04:00       72.0
2018-01-01 00:05:00       53.0
2018-01-01 00:06:00       62.0
2018-01-01 00:07:00       59.0
2018-01-01 00:08:00      117.0
2018-01-01 00:09:00       62.0
2018-01-01 00:10:00       65.0
2018-01-01 00:11:00       70.0
2018-01-01 00:12:00       49.0
2018-01-01 00:13:00       59.0
```

This data is a collection of daily heart rates from patients. I am trying to see if, based off their heart rate, I can find the time window that they are asleep.

I am not sure how to write a code that is able to identify the time window that the patient is asleep because every few minutes, there will be a spike in the data. For example, in the data provided from `2018-01-01 00:07:00 to 2018-01-01 00:08:00`, the `heartrate` jumped from 59 to 117. Can anyone suggest a way around this and a way to find the time window when the `Heartrate` is below the mean for a few hours?

Comment: If you think 6 hours is good time frame, keep 6 hours.. any outliers like `117` will be taken care as you will average 360 values.

Comment: Also, if you think values like `117` comes way to often then do the outlier treatment and then do the rolling window mean

Comment: @RahulAgarwal thank you for your comment. So what I tried was `patient['rollingmeanVal'] = patient.rolling('3T').heartrate.mean()`. And this did smoothen the data but I am still not sure how to code up something that is able to identify the period that the heartrate is bellow the mean heartrate.

Comment: I couldn't understand you completely, there is sort of circular reference in what you are asking. For your sample input can you provide sample output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your comments, you can find the rolling mean to 'smoothen' your signal using:

```
patient_data_df['rollingmeanVal'] = patient_data_df.rolling('3T').heartrate.mean()
```

Assuming you are using a dataframe and want to identify rows that have a HR bellow or equal to the mean you can use:

```
HR_mean = patient_data_df['rollingmeanVal'].mean()
selected_data_df = patient_data_df[patient_data_df['rollingmeanVal'] <= HR_mean]
```

Then, instead of dealing with the dataframe as a time-series dataframe, you can reset the index and generate a column called `index` with the datetime as values. Now that you have a dataframe with all values bellow the mean, you can group them into groups when there is more than 30 mins difference between each group. This is assuming that having fluctuating data for 30 mins is ok.

Assuming that the group with the most data is when the patient is asleep, you can identify that group. Using the first and last date of this group, you can then identify the time window that the patient is asleep.

Reset the index, adding a new col called `index` with the time-series data:

```
selected_data_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Group by:

```
selected_data_df['grp'] = selected_data_df['index'].diff().dt.seconds.ge(30 * 60).cumsum()
sleep_grp = selected_data_df.groupby('grp').count().sort_values(['grp']).head(1)
sleep_grp_index = sleep_grp.index.values[0]
sleep_df = selected_data_df[selected_data_df['grp'] == sleep_grp_index].drop('grp', axis=1)
```

Start of sleep time:

```
temp2_df['index'].iloc[0]
```

End of sleep time:

```
temp2_df['index'].iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Run Length Encoding function from base R for solving your problem. In step 1 you may calculate the rolling mean of your patients heart rate. You may use your solution or any [other](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsibble/vignettes/window.html). Afterwards you add a logic flag to your `data.frame`, e.g. `patient['lowerVal'] = patient['heartrate'] < patient['rollingmeanVal']`. Afterwards apply `rle` function on that variable `lowerVal`. As return you get the length of runs below and above mean. By applying `cumsum` on the `lengths` value, you get locations of your sleeping time frames.

Sorry. It is Python. Therefore, you may use the Python version of [Run Length Encoding](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/list-splitting-for-rle-compression-algorithm).